# Scanning text file line by line and reading line with unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I know there are a lot of different threads already like this, but nothing I can find seems to explain well enough exactly what I'm trying to do.

Basically I want to have a shell script that just goes through a text file, line by line, and searches for the words "Error" or "Exception". Whenever it comes across those words it would record the line number so I can later shoot the text file off in an email with the problem lines.

I've seen a lot of stuff that explains how to loop through a text file line by line, but I don't understand how I can run a regular expression on that line, because I'm not sure exactly how to use regular expressions with a shell script and also what variable each line is being stored in...

If anybody can clarify these things for me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous tools that automatically loop thru files. I would suggest a simple solution like:

```
 grep -inE 'error|exception' logfile > /tmp/logSearch.$$ 
 if [[ -s /tmp/logSearch.$$ ]] ;then
   mailx -s "errors in Log" < /tmp/logSearch.$$
 fi
 /bin/rm /tmp/logSearch.$$
```

use `man grep` to understand the options I'm supplying.

From `man bash

```
 -s file
True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm a bit confused. This is copying the entire line that has "error" or "exception" and tossing it in a temporary file, right?

Instead of that how can I keep the line numbers in an array and send that in an email? Because the line that has error or exception doesn't actually include all the info needed. The lines below it are where all the real details of the error are.

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot. I could just include -n in that and it'll do exactly what I want... I think?

Comment: @sil40: I'm glad this helped. `-n` prints the line numbers, so yes you get the info you need with some information included. ALSO, Some greps support a `context` parameter, meaning, show N lines surrounding the matched lines. Check you `man grep` to see if that is true for your version of grep. If that's not clear, but you find that there is a `context` option, just test it on one file, to see what happens; try `4` as a value for the surrounding context. Good lukc.

Comment: @sil40: Err, yep, I got that wrong too! not `-l` as I originally posted, but `-n` for numbered lines. I have edited my answer. See if you grep has `-A 4` (or any useful number) for **after** context. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using the grep command.  With it you can search for a specific string, output the line number and the line itself, and do much much more.

Here is a link to a site with practical examples of using the command:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/

Point #15 in the article may be of special interest to you.

Comment: Do you know if this will only run until it makes a hit? Because it's likely there could be dozens of errors or exceptions in a file.

Comment: This can run through the entire file or a set of files. It is the most versatile command in unix-based systems.  Have look through the man page for this for more details (type "man grep").  Please consider voting up if you find my answer helpful.  Cheers

Comment: Number 15 would actually be very useful, but I have no clue how to actually record those lines. It seems to just echo them out to the terminal, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Simply redirect the output to a file using '>'.  For example:  grep ... > myfile.txt